# How do airline pilots contact their company while in the air?

Tags: airliner, airline-operations, radio-communications

Sometimes airline pilots need to get in touch with their company while in the air, for example diagnosing cautionary messages or reporting a diversion. By what means is the communication channel established?

- VHF / HF radio? If that's the case, who allocates the frequencies to each airline?
- Satellite phone? (Are all aircrafts equipped with one in the cockpit?)
- Something else?

Comment: I think I recall from reading other Q&As here that they do use satellite phone, but they might use other ways too though.

Comment: HF, VHF/UHF. A lot [here](http://rockwellcollins.com/Services_and_Support/Information_Management/ARINC_Aviation/globalink-air-ground/air-ground_international_radio_service.aspx) about air-ground communications with different means. Overall ITU manages the allocation worldwide. US: FCC (member of the ITU conference) allocates frequencies to ARINC (Aeronautical Radio, Inc.), and ARINC deals with operators. See also: [N4JRI's page](http://www.qsl.net/n4jri/airlines.htm). [ACARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_Communications_Addressing_and_Reporting_System) in addition of voice.

Comment: Related (not duplicate): [What means do airline ground staff have to converse with pilots in flight?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5155/what-means-do-airline-ground-staff-have-to-converse-with-pilots-in-flight?lq=1)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While enroute the primary communication with company is via ACARS. (Aircraft Communications Addressing and Reporting System)

This is a digital datalink system and is kind of like sending text messages. On modern aircraft like a B777 it operates on HF, VHF, or SATCOM so there is coverage almost anywhere in the world.

If the aircraft is close to an airport with a company frequency, regular VHF radio communication can also be used.  Some airlines may even have company Peripheral stations (PAL) at certain locations so they can use a VHF radio to talk directly to Dispatch from hundreds of miles away.

In the USA, VHF company frequencies are allocated by Aviation Spectrum Resources, Inc. (ASRI) [ASRI Ground Station Administration Service (AGSA)](https://www.asri.aero/our-services/asri-ground-station-administration-service/)

SATCOM is also be used to make Satellite phone calls so we can talk directly to Dispatch or Maintenance from thousands of miles away. You can use pre-selected company numbers or manually enter any phone number.

Aircraft without SATCOM can use VHF or HF radios to contact ARINC (Aeronautical Radio, Incorporated) who can create a phone patch to any phone number.  [Aeronautical Radio, Incorporated (ARINC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARINC)

[image: SATCOM phone number menu]

Source: B777 Aircraft Operating Manual Volume 2 (2.23 Communications)

Comment: Great answer! If you would provide the source for your image, that would make it even better.

Comment: Thanks, I added the source. ( B777 Aircraft Operating Manual Volume 2 2.23 Communications)