# What do "LC/P" and "PTD" stand for in reference to airport communications?

Tags: airport, radio-communications, radio-navigation

When I pull up the [Colorado Springs (KCOS)](http://airnav.com/airport/KCOS) Airport Comm frequencies in Skyvector or in FAA database there are some frequency listed as "LC/P" and "PTD". Would someone explain what those acronyms stand for?

> LC/P: 119.9 360.6
>   PTD:    122.85 372.2

Comment: PTD means "Pilot to Dispatcher" according to the Airport / Facility Directory Legend.

Answer (score 3):

- **LC/P**: Local control, primary frequency, from **LC**, local control, which is a usual control position in the tower.

  "The Local Controller is primarily responsible for separating and providing safety alerts to aircraft in the airspace surrounding the airport and aircraft on the active runways" ([source](https://atbasics.faa.gov/public_page/177/Introduction%20to%20the%20ATC%20System%20and%20National%20Airspace%20System/41))

  [image]
  <sup>[Source](https://www.mitre.org/centers/center-for-advanced-aviation-system-development/where-we-focus/aviation-safety)</sup>
- **PTD**: As @Riccati commented, it means Pilot to Dispatcher, according to the Airport / Facility Directory Legend.

  Airlines are required by regulation to provide direct communication means for aircrew.

  [image]
  <sup>Aircraft dispatcher training ([source](https://www.baatraining.com/the-difference-between-a-flight-dispatcher-and-an-air-traffic-controller/))</sup>


  See also: [Can airline pilots communicate with dispatchers?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1897/)